# How to get current virtual path in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do you get the current path (url) from within an asp.net mvc view?

If there isn't a way to get it in the view, how can you get it in a controller so that it can be passed to the view?

### EDIT

I don't want the protocol and host portion of the url.

Comment: Mine should start after the protocol and domain name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will return the url in the view for you:

```
'<%=Url.RouteUrl(ViewContext.RouteData.Values)%>
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends on exactly what path you need, because there are lots of alternatives:

```
// given the url: http://mydomain/approot/my-route/?bar=baz

@Request.Url.PathAndQuery
// value: "/approot/my-route?bar=baz"
@Request.Path
@Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath
// value: "/approot/my-route"
@Request.ApplicationPath
// value: "/approot"
@Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
// value: "~/my-route"
@Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Substring(2)
// value: "my-route"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
<%= Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath %>
```

or

```
@Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath
```

if you are using Razor.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 <%= Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString() %>
```