# ASP.NET MVC View - Get Virtual Path for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC project works flawlessly when debugging locally.

However, once it is deployed to production, the true "Path" of the application is `http://servername/virtualpath/Home/Index`, just as an example.

There is some JavaScript that needs to declare the true `baseUrl` regardless of the environment it is deployed to.

In summary, I need a JavaScript variable to hold `http://servername/virtualpath/` when it is deployed to such an environment, or just `http://servername/` when it is running on an environment such as in debug.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445265/how-to-get-current-virtual-path-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the linked questions, if you're talking about static javascript files, you don't have access to your server code, so you've got a couple options:

You could put your javascript into an .aspx file or a regular controller action/view, so you do have access to your server code and can use things like `Url.Content` or `ResolveUrl`. If you do this, make sure you think about browser and/or server caching so that you don't waste resources.

**myfile.js.aspx**

```
<%@Page Language="C#" %>
<%
    Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));
%>

var imagePath = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/myimage.png") %>";
```

Or on your layout page (before any other `<script>` tags), you could put a hidden field or piece of javascript with the relative path, then call it:

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<script>
    window.resolveUrl = function(url) {
        return "@Url.Content("~")" + url; // Handle slashes, nulls, etc...
    };
</script>
```

**myfile.js**

```
var imagePath = resolveUrl("images/myimage.png");
```